# Intro/tour guide in react native application

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I need to implement an intro/tour in my react native application only when first time using the application.

I need to show a single part to mention what it does and at the same time hide the rest of the screen, like in the image below. So, basically my intro will be a guide on how to use the application each time shows something and hide the rest and we use the button "next" to get through it all.

[image]

I've already found this repository https://github.com/FuYaoDe/react-native-app-intro, but that's not exactly my purpose... any help?

So, basically, I need to make a very similar tour guide like this one https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide but in react native application

Comment: You can try https://github.com/jfilter/react-native-onboarding-swiper but it's also not 100% suitable. You could make screenshots of your views as the images and manually do the overlay/arrows with a graphics program.

Comment: They closed my SO question on the same topic.  Just found a RN version of Joyride:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-joyride

Comment: the best component to do this is https://github.com/prscX/react-native-app-tour